# ASP.net MVC new project cant find any referenced component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I created a new ASP.net MVC project(using MVC template) in VS2015 using .NET 4.6 Framework..

However when the project is created ,all the references (shown in the solution explorer ) have a yellow warning symbol next to it.. I even tried manually removing all references and adding them back individually.

The sample code I used for testing cannot use the references and gives me an error.
[Solution Explorer view and error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdzvQ.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete all references.You can add dll file from NuGet. Go to your project and right click and then click Manage NuGet Package.Add all types yellow warning symbol from online dll file.Like that
[image]

Comment: I tried that ,but any new DLL that get added using this method also have that warning triangle.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick search you may an illegal character in your path or something along those lines. 
Check this answer (seems very similar)
Check creating a new project in a simpler path

[Visual Studio- Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796041/visual-studio-illegal-characters-in-path)

Comment: If there was an illegal character in the file path VS would not have created the project. That is an Explorer error, usually.
I looked over the Error and could not see what you are referencing.

Comment: I think the key is that first error "The resolvePackageFileConflicts task was not found", I used that to search and found the SO question with same symptoms (but different cause). If you have to Nuget restore the basic .Net framework dlls I'd say you're starting on the wrong foot .

Answer (score 0):

This was a New MVC app you made? Strange all the packages would not be found. If you recompile the project, NuGet should restore any missing packages automatically.

To Manually restore the package goto Tool->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console

In the Console below, enter restore nuget.

For more information on NuGet Commands.
[NuGet Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)

Comment: nothing happens if nuget restore. This it what it says 

"nuget restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed."

Comment: Check the packages folder in the solution, see if they are present.
Question: Is this a New Project, or is this a Project download from  TFS/GIT or some other SVN?

Comment: Yes there are several packages in the packages folder.

It is a new project,not from any version control.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the VS Framework SDK location?

Comment: I guess this must be it,but I'm not at liberty uninstall/reinstall it. I also noticed that if I create a new "Website" as opposed to a new "Web Application" ,I don't see reference errors and warnings..strange