# Illegal characters in path : Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I'm not sure why but I simply just can't run my VS 2019 project(Azure Functions v3 proj) all of a sudden; it shows

> Illegal characters in path
> [image]

This is not an issue with the current branch that I'm working with; it's an issue with projects in all the branches. This is also the same path where the project was running successfully all this time. Rebuild , Restart of VS, Re-clone of the project, deleting the contents of the `bin` and the `obj` folders and then running again - I have tried everything, but nothing helped. I have also tried repairing and even re-installing VS but it was of no help.
The .csproj file looks completely fine to me at least:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This post also didn't help: [Visual Studio- Illegal characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796041/visual-studio-illegal-characters-in-path)

Any help whatsoever would be very helpful.

Comment: What's the path to the DLL (underneath the message box)?  There are a bunch of characters that cannot be in a pathname for a platform (see `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` and `Path.GetInvalidFileChars`).  Look to see if you have any of them somewhere path-ish

Comment: @Flydog57 I have given a more clearer picture of the path now(pardon me for the scribble, it is work related stuff) but one thing I can assure you that the path doesn't have any special characters and it is the same path where I was able to successfully run my code all this while

Comment: Try getting a non-VS file searcher (grep, findstr, ...) and search for each of the illegal characters in each file (excluding code files - you will get a lot of `|`, `<` and `>` characters in a .CS file).

Comment: You should also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228752/visual-studio-build-error-illegal-characters-in-path may be it will help you.

Comment: This might help.  Open the system internals process monitor, filter for visual studio and file operations != SUCCESS.  Repo the problem.  If that doesn't work, change the filter to only include things in your repo instead of visual studio (because it has a lot of sub-processes it runs) ..  You *might* see your problem.  I have found bugs this way when nothing else makes sense.

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe the path is too long?

Comment: @OptionalOption unfortunately there is no issue with the path. I have tried replicating the issue by placing the project folder just under C:\ and the issue stil persists

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to all of you for your suggestions to resolve this issue. After spending hours for a fix on this issue(which even included re-installing VS!), I finally chanced upon this life-saver of an article: [Visual Studio 2017/2019 fails when I create an Azure Functions project](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/visual-studio-2017-2019-fails-when-i-create-an-azure-functions-project-89e993ef31f).

The remedy is pretty simple, we just need to remove `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools` and this would do the magic.

I hope this answer is helpful for all those who would stumble upon this later.

Comment: By "remove `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools`", do you mean delete the directory?

Comment: Actually, I have answered my own question by trying it:  "yes".  Deleting the directory `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools` worked for me too.  Thanks!